# Dealing with blank or null in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

In my report, I have an expression which is used to pass a parameter to a child report parameter which is set to allow null values. The expression is :
=IIf(Parameters!Lead.Value = "False",Nothing,Fields!Paid.Value)

The above expression returns values only when Fields!Paid.Value is not blank. Therefore when Fields!Paid.Value is blank I get an error

"the value provided for the report parameter is not valid"

How do I modify my expression to parse these two conflicting issues?

What I want is to be able to return values when the Fields!Paid.Value is blank or when it is not. So at all time when the expression runs corresponding values are returned without the error stated above.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Try passing a value or an empty string instead of Nothing in the true part of your expression.

Comment: The Parameter!Lead.Value is Boolean parameter that has to be parsed first and then the Fields!Paid.Value will return data. Currently data are return when the Fields!Paid.Value is not empty or null but throws an error of
"the value provided for the report parameter is not valid" when when null or empty. How do I nest the the expression to return data? I tried :
=IIf(Parameters!Lead.Value = "False",Nothing,Fields!Paid.Value)
AND
IIF(Fields!paid.value is nothing ,nothing,Fields!paid.value)

and still get error of ....End of statement expected.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you do, wherever you have used the "Paid" parameter, set it to allow null value. Allow null only not blank.

The second thing about the expression, use something like this,

```
=IIF(Parameters!Lead.Value "FALSE", Nothing, IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Paid.Value),0,Fields!Paid.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya for the reply.

Comment: Thanks Aditya for the reply.
The issues is not in the Parameter!Lead.Value being "True" or "False". I want the False part as it is. The issue is that the Field!Paid.Value only return records when Paid Column is not empty or blank. It fails to return record when value in Field.Paid.Value is blank. The first condition being true, how do I ask Field!Paid.Value to return nothing if empty? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks.
The Parameter!Lead.Value is a Boolean data type. Therefore set to False and that is fine. It cannot be null otherwise Field!Paid.Value will not run. 
That being said, I want that when the Lead parameter is checked, paid.value should run and does run fine when no blank field is coming from the database but fails when there is a blank. How to I nest iif function to parse these correctly or how do I nest the switch function. 
Thanks for the concern.

Comment: Yes, I made the change, plz chk the updated one with nested iif, which replace null Paid value to 0.

Comment: Thank you.
I think we're getting  close. But it won't let me preview, resulting in an error. It found a problem with the second IIF function of the expression. 
You've got the idea. The challenge now is modifying the expression to not result in an error. I appreciate your help. Please share on how to resolve it. Thank you.